# Knockout.Js selectedOptions filtered from second collection

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am binding a collection to a select multi, some of the items in the collection are also in a second collection, i would like to set these as the selectedOptions in the select multi.

I was hoping to use a ko.utils.arrayFilter to do this but don't seem able to filter one collection from the other.

http://jsfiddle.net/dumbarse/BcUBK/

```
<select data-bind="options:availableThings,optionsText: 'Title', selectedOptions: selectedComputeThings" size="5"  multiple="true"></select>
        var initialThingsModel = [
            {"Id":1,"Title":"First"},
            {"Id":2,"Title":"Next"},
            {"Id":3,"Title":"Another"},
            {"Id":4,"Title":"Last"}
        ];
           var initialSelectedThingsModel = [
            {"Id":2,"Title":"Next"},
            {"Id":4,"Title":"Last"}];

    var viewModel = {
        availableThings: ko.observableArray(initialThingsModel),   
        selectedThings:  ko.observableArray(initialSelectedThingsModel)
    };
    viewModel.selectedComputeThings = ko.computed(function() { return ko.utils.arrayFilter(viewModel.availableThings(), function(item) { return item.Id == selectedThings.Id;}) });

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should revise your `computed` and write something like this:

```
viewModel.selectedComputeThings = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(
        initialThingsModel,
        function(thing){ 
            return ko.utils.arrayFirst(
                initialSelectedThingsModel,
                function(sel){ return sel.Id == thing.Id; }
            );
        }
    );
});
```

Works: http://jsfiddle.net/BcUBK/1/

**Update:**

To track selection you don't need `computed` - just simple `observableArray` (oh, you alraedy have `selectedThings` in your model!). Just fill this up with refs to selected things.

Slightly modify your `selectedThings` declaration:

```
selectedThings:  ko.observableArray([])
```

Convert `computed` to simple function that assigns refs to `selectedThings` observable array:

```
viewModel.preselectThings = function() {
    viewModel.selectedThings(ko.utils.arrayFilter(
        initialThingsModel,
        function(thing){ 
            return ko.utils.arrayFirst(
                initialSelectedThingsModel,
                function(sel){ return sel.Id == thing.Id; }
            );
        }
    ));
};
```

Add function call anywhere before/after `ko.applyBindings`:

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

viewModel.preselectThings();
```

And change `selectedComputeThings` to `selectedThings` everywhere in your markup.

Profit!

http://jsfiddle.net/BcUBK/3/

Comment: seems to work ok but then the computed selectedComputeThings does not update when you change the selection in the list, http://jsfiddle.net/dumbarse/BcUBK/2/, any thoughts?

Comment: I see what you did, thanks for this, i am struggling a bit with the knockout documentation and also wondering if knockout is the right thing to use. Thanks again!